# Cannot see option to 'Add Application Insights Telemetry to Project'

Tags: wcf, azure, azure-web-roles, azure-application-insights, telemetry

I have an existing web role that I deploy to Azure.  Now I would like to try out Application Insights but I do not see an option to 'Add Application Insights Telemetry to Project'.  I installed all the latest updates and if I try adding another web role project to my Azure deployment that new project has the option to add Application Insights.

Any ideas would be greatly appreciated.

Thank You!

Answer (score 1):

I believe VSIX checks if ApplicationInsights.config is added to the project. If it is present the option to add is not available.

Comment: depending on which version of vs you are on, sometimes it just looks for the appinsights.config file, and other versions looks for the config file and/or the presence of specific nuget packages.

Answer (score 0):

I think I figured this out.  Somehow telemetry was already added to my project, and that is probably why the menu option was not available.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into the same problem then found another option called overview after right clicking my project. Option might be available for other people so posting here as I didn't find this information elsewhere.

Right click project > Overview > Connected services > Monitoring with application insights > follow set up with azure account.

Also had to follow this post as .config file didn't add
https://stackoverflow.com/a/38060313/7030091