# Cannot add Application Insights to project Failed to install package Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.Web

Tags: c#, azure, azure-application-insights

Hi I am trying to log exceptions using Nlog to Application Insights, but when I am trying to add it gives me the following error as in the screen shot.

[image]][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fr1mw.jpg)

Comment: What version of NuGet do you have? Might try updating the NuGet manager. I found a similar post on a Microsoft forum that stated if it was older than 2.8 you could get this error.

Comment: My nuget manager version is 3.4.4

Comment: what version of VS, and what version of the developer analytics tools?  what's usually happening in this case is that nuget is verifying dependencies, but only looking at the location where application insights's nuget packages are (that directory) instead of using all sources.  I thought we'd fixed this in newer versions of the developer analytics tools.  if updating those doesn't work, you might need to manually add the ApplicationInsights.Web package manually from nuget package manager, then use "configure application insights" *after that* to set the resource.

Comment: I find a similar [SO thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37852878/cannot-add-application-insights-failed-to-install-package-microsoft-web-infra), you could try the solution.

Comment: Do you have any update about this thread?